# How order_by some models with an transformed fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-order-by

I have a model called Topic with slug Field.

I have an Hash with transformed text for each slug.

```
names: {
    foo: 'cell',
    bar: 'yetto',
    baz: 'azkaban'
}
```

I need to order by name, but name field don't exist in DB, only "slug".

In this exemple, result should be:

```
baz => Azkaban
foo => Cell
bar => Yetto
```

for this moment

```
Topic.all.order(slug: :asc)

Bar => yetto
Baz => azkaban
Foo => cell
```

So how can I ordered with transformed field?

Comment: Are you storing `slug` as a hash in the database?

Comment: @papirtiger what did you mean? slug is a string in DB. (exemple: slug = 'foo', and the transformed name is 'cell')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, invert `names`, then use `sort_by` on the collection of `Topics`.

```
inverted_names = names.invert

Topics.all.sort_by{ |a| inverted_names[a[:slug]] }
```

This will yield a collection of all topics, sorted by your mapping. For example, given a collection

```
collection = [
  { title: "Banana", slug: "cell" },
  { title: "Orange", slug: "azkaban" },
  { title: "Apples", slug: "yetto" }
]
```

The `sort_by` above would yield the following

```
[
  {:title=>"Apples", :slug=>"yetto"}, 
  {:title=>"Orange", :slug=>"azkaban"}, 
  {:title=>"banana", :slug=>"cell"}
]
```

Comment: simply: ```Topic.all.sort_by{ |t| names[t.slug.to_sym] }``` Thx.

Comment: Sorry, I had trouble understanding whether the keys or values were your slugs :)